what is the function if I add a multiplier to a gaussian distribution
Gaussian distribution:
$$
y = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$
we know that it has only 2 parameters and it has a peak $y_{\text{max}} = \dfrac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}$ at $x=\mu$
but I found that the peak is usually too short to curve-fit my data
so I am thinking, is:
$$
y = \frac{A}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$
a Gaussian distribution?
This curve has a peak of $y_{\text{max}} = \dfrac{A}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}$, what is its new standard deviation?


For a function to be a PDF, the area under the function has to integrate up to 1.0.  Since you have scaled the PDF in amplitude, but not in width, you no longer have a PDF.

To fit your data, estimate $\mu$ first, and then estimate $\sigma$.  If you can't get a good fit, perhaps your data is not Gaussian distributed and you might be better off trying to fit it to another distribution model.

It's not a Gaussian because a Gaussian distribution is a probability distribution. It is a Bell curve, and it certainly can be used to,fit date if the data is not a frequency set.

@ThomasAndrews OK it is a curve so that it can use to fit, but it cannot be used to calculate a distribution (because integral is not 1).

Well, there is a difference between a distribution and a probability distribution. But if you are working in probability, often the shorter name is used as a synonym, because it is what you are talking about most of the time. @Firestar-Reimu

Please tell us where your data came from, as it seems possible you are using the wrong tool for your job. "Curve fitting" usually means finding a function that gets as close as possible to a set of points, whereas a normal distribution usually arise in a probability measure situation. If you are actually curve fitting, you should probably be looking for classes of splines.

@JonathanZ it is a series of flux - velocity graph (that is, spectra) in radio astronomy, and a cloud will have a bell curve, you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79191628/how-to-check-if-my-spectrum-has-one-symmetrical-peak-that-is-gaussian/79195757#79195757

Ah, I see. First, since every mathematician is going to tell you that a Gaussian has total internal = 1, you could just renormalize your data so your y-axis was "percent of total", and that would be equivalent to setting your A=1. Second, anything people tell you to do about fitting a Gaussian is going to be thrown off by that significant bump heading towards the y axis that your graphs indicate. I'd suggest asking in the signal processing stack exchange your "do I have a single bump" question.

And as for whether or not it's symmetric, I think the statisticians have good ways to measure that. "Cross validated" is the name of the statistics stack exchange.
